# How to extract data through IsoDep technology - NFC(Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, ndef

I'm using NFC technology for one of my projects in Android. I have successfully implemented the Tag detection and based on the Tag I know which class I need to use to extract the data. But there is one problem the card which I need to use/tap to get the data is using the IsoDep technology rather than NDEF one. I know how to extract the data from a card which is working on NDEF technology but I'm getting stuck here because of the IsoDep technology. I'm sharing my code snippet with this question for better understanding.

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

Tag tag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
IsoDep isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag);
isoDep.connect();
//code to get the data from card
isoDep.close()
}
```

So here I'm getting TAG_DISCOVERED through NFCAdapter and inside the condition I'm getting IsoDep, tech.NFcA, NdefFormattable as tag variable value. I'm creating the instance of IsoDep class and calling connect() method. Here I'm getting IOException everytime I'm trying to start the connection to read the data I don't know why !!! 
Can anyone help me to solve this? Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should check whether or not the `.get` call worked by checking whether `isoDep == null`.

As for your `IOException`, it is hard to identify the specific cause of the issue if you cannot provide the code. Methods for extracting data from tags vary from manufacturer to manufacturer. You noted that the tag also supports `NfcA`, it might be worth investigating if this technology doesn't work too.

However, some things to consider:

- Have you tried with more than 1 tag? Can you confirm the issue isn't related to the tag?
- Do you have the NFC permission setup correctly? An otherwise illogical IOException could be because of this.
- Are you calling `.close()` from another thread? This will cause the IOException.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @henrycjc I have already checked the object of IsoDep is not null in my case. Also for all other Technologies I'm getting null so I think I need to use IsoDep technology only in this case.

Comment: Just to clarify, the null check is just a good practise and not a solution to the problem. But, are you saying that NfcA appears in `Tag.getTechList()` but you can't successfully `.get`? Are you sure you haven't already connected with another technology? Also can you address the IOException question? It is still a little unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Ok so I have checked it again I'm getting successfully Nfca.get(tag). And regarding the IOException while using IsoDep technology to perform any operation we need to connect() it first but I'm getting IO exception while doing this. Hope you got this time.

Comment: Even for the Nfca object when I'm trying to do connect(); it's giving me the IOException.